# rails error: syntax error unexpected end of input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error

```
  def create
    @diary = Diary.find(params[:diary_id])
    @diary_page = @diary.diary_pages.create(params[:diary_page].permit(:text))
    redirect_to diary_path(@diary)
  end
```

Hi above is my controller method create. It is giving me following error.

```
diary_pages_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input ����@diary = Diary.find(params[:diary_id]) ^
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Could you show your all diary_pages_controller.rb file?

Comment: Maybe an encoding issue? Do you have tabs instead of spaces in your controller?

Comment: @sebbo: how does tabs/spaces matter? in Ruby only line breaks are checked.

Comment: Just thought that because of the strange error message something is wrong with the first two characters of line 20 of your controller. So maybe instead of spaces - your text editor/IDE placed something else there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was such a dumb question. My editor added some bad characters at the beginning of the line.

**Fixed the error by re-indenting the line.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not an indenting problem just add another `end`.